# Web.config file with appSetting Value containing "&" not being parsed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="myKeyName" value="DFG&y:yd%yeZ" />
  </appSettings>
```

I have a web.config file in an ASP.NET MVC application. In my appSettings section, i have a key whose value contains a character that makes the web.config invalid.

The character is the "&" in value="DFG&y:yd%yeZ", if i remove it, the app works fine, when i put it back i get the error below.

> > Configuration Error  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
> >     Please review the specific error details below and modify your
> >     configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line
>   25, position 61.

And my key below is highlighted in red.

```
 <add key="myKeyName" value="DFG&y:yd%yeZ" />
```

Is the "&" prohibited in the a web.config's appSettings key Value?

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace the special char "&" by:

```
&amp;
```

Here is a [list of special chars](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php)

Comment: Doesn't then this complicate reading the key value in C#. Would my value be read correctly as "DFG&y:yd%yeZ" OR plainly as "DFG&amp;y:yd%yeZ"?

Comment: It should be read simply as "DFG&amp;y:yd%yeZ" and you may need to change the "%", I do not remember very well right now.

Comment: so if "DFG&y:yd%yeZ" is a password, replacing the & with &amp; breaks the password validity. Any idea how best handle this break.